# Why after press enter key, it post back to start page not same page that i press a key in it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I press enter in pages that don't have any default button, the page will post back to start page, it's odd because it must post back in same page that i press enter in it not start page.
how can I fix it?

Comment: your question is not clear....!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As ASP.NET WebForms generally wrap a `form` tag around the entire content of the site, I would guess that you have a `Button` or `ImageButton` near the start of your content which links to the homepage.

Maybe the site logo is an `ImageButton` with a server-side event to redirect to the homepage?

Without a default button specified, the page is actioning the first button within the form when the keyboard enter button is pressed.

---

Short term solution: Ensure you have a `Panel` with a `DefaultButton` around every "form" you have.

Long term solution: Move away from WebForms :)